# jQuery fetch disabled select option value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select id="test_me" name="test_me" disabled>
 <option value="">Please select</option>
 <option value="1">Test One</option>
 <option value="2" selected>Test Two</option>
 <option value="3">Test Three</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" value="" name="test_hidden" id="test_hidden">
```

Here option `Test Two` is selected and disabled. The below code fetches select value when dropdown is enabled and value is changed.

```
//pass value to hidden input
$('#test_me').change(function () {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $('input#test_hidden').val(id);
})
```

How can I pass selected option value i.e. `2` to my hidden input, when dropdown is disabled and value is selected ?

Comment: This issue is reported at http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13097 and marked as wont fix.

Comment: what's the problem, you cannot access the value if the list is disabled?

Comment: Doesn't `$("#test_me").val()` do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is reported at http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13097 and marked as wont fix. for reason:

> The long-standing logic in .val() ensures that we don't return disabled options in a select-multiple. The change just applies the same behavior for select-one now for consistency.

Alternative for this would be to use selectedindex property of select to target option by index:

```
$("#test_me option").eq($("#test_me").prop("selectedIndex")).val();
```

**Complete Snippet:**

```
var id =  $("#test_me option").eq($("#test_me").prop("selectedIndex")).val();;
$('input#test_hidden').val(id);
```

Comment: Milind Anantwar, my code works when dropdown value is changed. Can we make it conditional based i.e. `Call my code when dropdown value is changed` else `Call your code if dropdown is disabled` ?

Comment: You can use `if($(this).is(':disabled'))` condition for making the decision which code to be used. But i don't understand how change event will occur when select is disabled?? you can not select option when for disabled select.

Comment: Agree. But for some conditons the select will be enabled. How can I combine both codes on condtional basis ?

Comment: `if($(this).is(':disabled')) <my code> else <your code>`

Comment: The code `if($("#test_me").is(':disabled')){ //pass value to hidden input when select value is disabled
       var id =  $("#task_me").eq($("#task_me").prop("selectedIndex")).val();
       $('input#test_hidden').val(id);
       }else{
        $('#test_me').change(function () {  //pass value to hidden input when select is changed
        var id = $(this).val();
        $('input#test_hidden').val(id);
        });
    }` does not seem to work.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: can you create the fiddle with problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73896/discussion-between-milind-anantwar-and-slimshadddyyy).

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//pass value to hidden input
    $(document).ready(function(e) {

    var sel = $("#test_me").val();
    $("#test_hidden").val(sel);

    });

   </script>


<select id="test_me" name="test_me" disabled>
 <option value="">Please select</option>
 <option value="1">Test One</option>
 <option value="2" selected>Test Two</option>
 <option value="3">Test Three</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" value="" name="test_hidden" id="test_hidden">
```